# Crawler get Info about pages (Scrapy)

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

How to implement a crawler (using SCRAPY) that get all information about a page. For example, size of images, size of CSS files and save in .txt file (page1.txt, page2.txt)

I tried this with images:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name="Test"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/page1.html", "http://www.example.com/page2", ]

    def start_requests(self):
            for url in self.start_urls:
                    yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait':5})

    def parse(self, response):

            for url_image in response.xpath('//img/@src').extract():
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=url_image, callback=self.parse_image)

    def parse_image(self, response):
            with open('page1.txt', 'a+') as f:
                    f.write(str(len(response.body)))
```

This code would save all size images in page1.txt, how to send parameters to parse_image()? For example, filename to parse_image() function.

Splash browser does exactly what I need --> [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbJsr.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transfer data between your parse methods you can use `Request`s `meta` attribute:

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = {'foo': 'bar'}
    yield Request(url, self.parse2, meta=data)

def parse2(self, response):
    data = response.meta
    # {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! More one question, can I return any value from parse2()? Does Parse2() method return only scrapy.Request class??

Comment: Yes you can,scrapy parse methods are expected to return or generate Request or Item/dictionary objects.